# VLCKit: VLCMediaPlayerDelegate in a Cocoa Application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, libvlc

I'm trying to develop a Cocoa Application for Mac OSX 10.10 that implements some video streaming in VLCKit.
Now:

1. I've compiled the **.framework** library and I've imported it in Xcode.
2. I've added a **Custom View** in my  Main.storyboard and set it to a **VLCVideoView**

[image: The View]

3. In my ViewController.h i've implemented the **VLCMediaPlayerDelegate** to receive notification from the player

Here's my code:

**viewController.h**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <VLCKit/VLCKit.h>

@interface ViewController : NSViewController<VLCMediaPlayerDelegate>

@property (weak) IBOutlet VLCVideoView *_vlcVideoView;

//delegates
- (void)mediaPlayerTimeChanged:(NSNotification *)aNotification;

@end
```

---

**viewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController
{
    VLCMediaPlayer *player;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [player setDelegate:self];

    [self._vlcVideoView setAutoresizingMask: NSViewHeightSizable|NSViewWidthSizable];
    self._vlcVideoView.fillScreen = YES;

    player = [[VLCMediaPlayer alloc] initWithVideoView:self._vlcVideoView];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://MyRemoteUrl.com/video.mp4"];

    VLCMedia *movie = [VLCMedia mediaWithURL:url];
    [player setMedia:movie];
    [player play];
}

- (void)mediaPlayerTimeChanged:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    //Here I want to retrieve the current video position.
}

@end
```

The video start and play correctly. However I can't get the delegate to work.
Where I am wrong?

Here are my questions:

1. How can I setup the delegate to receive notifications about the current player time?
2. How can I read the NSNotification? (I'm not really used to Obj-C)

Thank you in advance for any answer!

Comment: For my first question I've found the solution! I've forgot to add this lines:
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(mediaPlayerTimeChanged:) name:VLCMediaPlayerTimeChanged object:nil];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've managed it!

1. *How can I setup the delegate to receive notifications about the current player time*? I had to add an **observer** to **NSNotificationCenter**.

Here's the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   [player setDelegate:self];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(mediaPlayerTimeChanged:) name:VLCMediaPlayerTimeChanged object:nil];
}
```

2. *How can I read the NSNotification?* I had to retrieve the VLCMediaPlayer object inside the notification.

Code:

```
- (void)mediaPlayerTimeChanged:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
   VLCMediaPlayer *player = [aNotification object];
   VLCTime *currentTime = player.time;
}
```